# C++ generic rvalue overload

Tags: c++, operator-overloading, rvalue

I'm currently trying to refactor some code which uses a primitive type into something which I can tuck setters and getters into them. I wanted to make the change to the underlying code transparent, and at first I though C++'s operator overloads would help me out there.

Let's suppose I want to make an "augmented `int`" type, for instance, that can be treated just like a regular `int`, but allows for further action wherever I assign to it, and just assignment - all other properties of an `int`, such as adding with `+=`, should be preserved.

At first I first though that if I encapsulated the `int` inside some struct, and filled out the `operator=` overloads, I'd be set, like in the following example:

```
#include<iostream>

typedef struct PowerInt{
  int x;

  PowerInt(){
    cout << "PowerInt created\n";
    x = 0;
  }
  ~PowerInt(){
    cout << "PowerInt destroyed\n";
  }

  void operator=(int other){
    cout << "PowerInt received " << other << "\n";
    this->x = other;
  }
}PowerInt;

int main(){
  PowerInt a;
  a = 3;
  return 0;
}
```

The code compiles and runs as expected, but as soon as I try making anything else a regular int could do, like `cout << a`, or `a += 2`, or even a simple `int b = a;` assignment the compiler complains about the operators `<<` and `+=` missing.

Fair enough; I then though that, at least for `<<` and "assigment `=`", I could get by using some sort of "generic rvalue operator", or some kind of method which returns `PowerInt.x` wherever my `a` is used as an rvalue, automatically making expressions like `int c = (a + 3);` and `if (a == 3) {}` valid.

Problem is, I can't find a way to implement this idiom, and this mostly likely has to do with either my little understanding of how operator overloading works in C++, or some language feature I'm not yet aware of. Is it possible to accomplish what I'm trying here?

Comment: I don't see the relation to [rvalue](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3601602/what-are-rvalues-lvalues-xvalues-glvalues-and-prvalues)

Comment: There are some unnecessary C-isms here y'know

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit You could point them to me, given that after programming in C for almost a decade I'm now just scratching C++'s surface, y'know. :)

Comment: `typedef struct T { } T;` .... just `struct T {};` will be fine. If you wanted to share your `struct` definition with C code then okay keep it compatible, but as this one has C++ class features you definitely aren't doing that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want your `PowerInt` to be convertible to a normal `int` you can create a user-defined conversion operator:

```
operator int() const
{
  return x;
}
```

Any operator that's not defined for `PowerInt` will then use the operator defined for a normal `int`.

P.S The `typedef struct` isn't necessary in C++.

Comment: Silly, silly me. This solves the problem in the exact way I intended to.